# Labelling Icons in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I am using leaflet to create a set of points, but I want to view which one was plotted first, last, etc. Is there way to label them such that when the first point is plotted, it will plot a circle with a 1 in it? Then plot the next one with a 2, and continued?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Leaflet.Icon.Glyph](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.Icon.Glyph) to display little numbers inside the point markers.